# regular expression to allow alphanumerique (upper and lower) and comma delimiter

Tags: jquery

I was trying to make condition on some fields to have only uppercase, lowercase, numbers and comma as delimiter.
On field that can have a project name, I don't need comma so what I found was this but, I can't have uppercase

```
$var = $var.replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()-_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/? ])+/g, '-').replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g,'');
```

Comment: Well, there's the `i` modifier, so there's that.

Comment: This feels like the wrong solution. What about characters like `é`, `·`, and `€`? If you want to be super restrictive make a whitelist `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you should use the `i` modifier, to make your regex case-insensitive.

You should also reverse your thinking process, instead of banning a lot of characters, you should allow only the characters you want :

```
$var = $var.replace(/([^A-Z0-9,])+/gi, '');
```

In this example, I :

- replaced your long char list by `[^A-Z0-9,]`, which means *any non alpha-numerical or non-comma character*
- Added the `i` modifier
- Updated the replace string from `-` to  (empty)
- Deleted the second regex, which is now useless.

[Try it online !](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lorcs8p/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. $var = $var.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9,]/gi,''); did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please [upvote and accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if you're satisfied so it may help others.